Symfony PHPUnit disable custom specific event during testing
PHP8.3
Symfony7.0
Is it possible to disable specific event listeners during ApiTests with PHPUnit?
I have searched a lot but i can not figure it out, how this should work.
Another option can be also to disable the service which is called through the event.
I have played with this option in the tests but it seems that when a service is once initialized through event listener there is no chance to stop/kill the service, right?

Is it a unit test? a functional one? can you show some code supporting your question?

Hello, sorry for the late reply.
My question was about the ability to disable certain events in the test environment.
I don't have any code sources. This was a consideration before starting development.
I haven't found any information about this possibility yet.
Thank you very much.
